# IONIC 4 styles are changed after view refresh

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

IONIC 4 app changes styles after refreshing the view.

The issue can even be replicated on a simple IONIC 4 default demo app which can be created by the following command: "ionic start blablabla tabs --type=angular".

After the app is launched it has one set of styles, then after simply just refreshing the view (ctrl+R/cmd+R) it has different styles. What is the reason for this and how I could fix it?

The following link is a screenshot of the issue, on the right hand side is the expected styles that should be applied and on the left are the ones that are applied after the refresh:

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUBkl.jpg

**ionic info:**

- ionic (Ionic CLI): 4.10.1
- Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 4.0.1
- @angular-devkit/build-angular: 0.12.4
- @angular-devkit/schematics: 7.2.4
- @angular/cli: 7.2.4
- @ionic/angular-toolkit: 1.4.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two different views are normal, they represent MD and IOS styles.

For example look at the two icons:

[image]

You can change the styles if you select a android or ios device in the inspector in your browser and refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it seems regardless of what type of devices is selected, it always defaults to the same styles after refresh. Is there a way to force to use specific styles regardless of the platform?

Comment: this worked for me. I was selecting iPhone in developer tools I used to think it depended on resolution only but ionic actually switches styles on selecting Android/iOS device. Thanks!